# When im converting the predicted value this gives me IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the file from post request
        f = request.files['file']

        # Save the file to ./uploads
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(
            basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)

     # Make prediction
                preds = model_predict(file_path, model)
                print('make predict', preds)
                # Process your result for human
                pred_class = preds.argmax(axis=-1)  # Simple argmax
                print(pred_class)
                # pred_class = decode_predictions(preds, top=1)   # ImageNet Decode
                result = str(pred_class[0][0][1])  # Convert to string
                return result
            return None
```

result = str(pred_class[0][0][1])  # Convert to string
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2021 13:10:07] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: Could you please provide a simple code that could be run independently which reproduces only the proble you are facing? I mean - what is the pred_class ? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelSidorov simply it shows this                                                                               preds [[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
make predict [[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[1]   - simply these are the print statements [1] means the index of the class

Comment: Add to your question the result of the `print(pred_class)` statement.  The values you show in the comment are hard to read, and don't appear to be relevant.   You/we need to figure out what is wrong with the 3 level indexing.

Answer (score 0):

If `make_predict = [[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]`, than you try to access the first index of the integer `0` that you get from `pred_class[0][0]`, so by removing the redundant indexer in `result = str(pred_class[0][0][0])` and changing it to `result = str(pred_class[0][0])  # Convert to string` should fix the problem.

Cheers.

Comment: yes its working but when the return statement execute, it shows an array like Result : [0] so the "0" shows the relevant class index. How to display the class name basically a string